# C++ std::list использование памяти

Tags: c++, arduino

Только начинаю работать с std::list в Arduino (компилятор C++ 11)
Нужно положить в std::list класс:

```
class TTimerData : public Printable  // для возможности прямой печати
{
  public:
  float t1; 
  float t2; 
  uint32_t time_on; 
  char _tt[20]; // для увеличения размера класса
  String str;


  TTimerData(float ptick1_ON,   float ptick2_OFF, uint32_t ptime_on);
  TTimerData( uint32_t ptime_on);

  // операторы нужны для list.sort()
  bool operator >(TTimerData const & a);
  bool operator <(TTimerData const & a);

  size_t printTo(Print& p) const;
};
```

Хранить в std::list можно двумя способами:

1 способ: хранить указатели на объекты:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<TTimerData> TTimerDataPtr    ; 
typedef std::list<TTimerDataPtr> TTimerDataList;
```

Добавление элемента:

```
auto new_order = std::make_shared<TTimerData>(0,0,i); 
lst.push_back(new_order);
```

shared_ptr нужны для автоматического освобождения памяти после удаления элемента из list.

2 способ: хранить сами объекты:

```
typedef std::list<TTimerData> TListInside;
```

Добавление:

```
lst.emplace_back(0,0,i);  // создает объект внутри List и сразу вызывает конструктор TTimerData
```

ВОПРОС: какой способ хранения объекта в std::list предпочтительнее (ну или более правильный)?

Я провел в эксперимент, положил в list 200 объектов, в обоих случаях после удаления всех объектов из list ESP.getFreeContStack() и ESP.getFreeHeap() показывают значение, бывшее до момента добавления (т.е. утечки памяти нет)

Опасение у меня вызывает второй способ - когда вызывается метод lst.emplace_back(0,0,i); Я не совсем уверен что для выделения места он использует malloc - а не стек. 
  list используется глобально и если память под новый объект выделяется в стеке - то ничего хорошего меня не ждет.
  Эксперимент правда показал, что malloc в этом случае используется, но полной уверенности у меня нет.

Comment: а с чего бы утечка должна появиться? более правильного способа нет, нужно выбрать на основе того, как вы хотите работать элементами вашего list. Самому контейнеру, по большому счёту, вообще до лампочки что вы в нём храните. Вы хотите определять время жизни ваших объектов сами(условно)? или чтобы они хранились только пока находятся в контейнере?

Comment: Сами объекты живут только пока находятся в list. При удалении объекта из list  (любым методом) я хочу чтобы занятая им память освобождалась

В принципе конечно применимы оба способа. 

Опасение у меня вызывает второй способ - когда вызывается метод lst.emplace_back(0,0,i);  Я не совсем уверен что для выделения места он использует malloc - а не стек. list используется глобально и если память под новый объект выделяется в стеке - то ничего хорошего меня не ждет

Comment: Что бы вы std::list не хранили, будь это  умный указатель,  обычный указатель или обьект, контейнер  будет использовать  свой распределитель(по умолчанию  std::allocator), и будет хранить свои обьекты одинаковым образом, и память под новый обьект никак не может выделяться в стеке, если вы не написали специальный распределитель для него

Answer (score 1):

> `shared_ptr` нужны для автоматического освобождения памяти после удаления элемента

`std::list` в любом случае сам освобождает память, которую занимал элемент, после его удаления. `shared_ptr` для этого не нужен.

> какой способ хранения объекта в std::list предпочтительнее

Если вам не нужны никакие особенности `shared_ptr`, то лучше его не использовать.

> Опасение у меня вызывает второй способ - когда вызывается метод `lst.emplace_back(0,0,i);` Я не совсем уверен что для выделения места он использует `malloc` - а не стек

Он никак не может использовать стек, только кучу. (Хотя скорее `new`, а не `malloc`.)

Память, которую функция выделяет в стеке, освобождается после выхода из функции. Если бы `emplace_back` создавала новый объект на стеке, как бы она могла нормально работать? Этот новый объект уничтожался бы сразу после выхода из `emplace_back`.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, ответ частично неверный.
Без shared_ptr идет утечка памяти (написал тест)

Comment: код:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZWDdza-TgoEvWBeTdXFgtWvWgnrzi1D_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ГайратВласов Если память утекает действительно из `std::list`, тогда проблема не в отсутствии `shared_ptr`, и его добавление ничего не должно менять. Можете отредактировать вопрос и добавить код туда? (А то сомневаюсь, что кто-то еще полезет скачивать файл с кодом.) И скажите, что именно печатают все эти вызовы `PrintHeap`.

Comment: PrintHeap печатает свободную память esp8266 в heap и в стеке. В код я добавил третий метод - строго по Вашей методе -  testList3 - хранение в list указателей на объект без shared_ptr. Вызов показывает что идет утечка памяти - поэтому использование shared_ptr при хранении в list указателей обязательно!

Comment: @ГайратВласов *"PrintHeap печатает свободную память esp8266 в heap и в стеке"* Это я понял. Я имею в виду, какие именно числа выводятся для вашего кода?

Comment: Запуск test : 52304
testList1 Start :  heap : 52304
testList1 List заполнен :  heap : 42944
testList1 List sort :  heap : 42944
--------------------
testList1 change_String1 :  heap : 29264
testList1 List clear :  heap : 52304


testList2 Start :  heap : 52304
testList2 List заполнен :  heap : 40784

testList2 change_String :  heap : 29264
testList2 Конец :  stack : 3420 heap : 52304

======================

testList3 Start :  stack : 3420 heap : 52304
testList3 List заполнен :  stack : 3420 heap : 45824
--------------------

Конец test : 47264

Comment: переводы строки съелись - видно что testlist1 и testlist2 - утечки памяти нет. testlist3 - есть. Вы можете код и у себя запустить - вызвав функции контроля памяти, доступные в Вашей среде разработки

Comment: yeld() служит для обработки внутренних событий esp8266, без него soft reset настает

Comment: @ГайратВласов Добавьте и полный код, и этот вывод в вопрос. Вряд ли кто-то полезет искать его в комментарии.

Comment: Вопроса то нет - я сказал и показал что Вы неправы когда говорите что в std::list можно хранить указатели на объект и при удалении элементов память под объектами будет освобождаться сама. shared_ptr ведь не зря придумали :)

Comment: @ГайратВласов Нет, здесь что-то не так. Память освобождается сама в любом случае.

Comment: @ГайратВласов Ваш код запустить не могу, потому что там слишком много специфичных для ардуины вещей. Вот пример на чистом С++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac8df92555a93c9b

Comment: спасибо за пример, пытаюсь запустить Ваш код, пока не получается адаптировать - у Вас С++14, а у меня C++11 - пока определение map не проходит :) Можете подсказать как правильно переписать std::less<> на то что у меня в заголовке указано:  typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>

Comment: @ГайратВласов `std::less<>` -> `std::less<void *>`.

Comment: Ваш код я понял (запустить правда  удалось :)). Но в итоге Вы все же не просто  храните указатель на объект, а определяете свой CustomAllocator + operator delete  + map которые в совокупности и определяют освобождение памяти. Решение без сомнения изящное ! (правда требует C++14) Но, на мой взгляд, ничем не лучше использования shared_ptr :)

Comment: @ГайратВласов Неправильно поняли. Свои `operator new` и `delete`, и этот `map` нужны только чтобы печатать количество занятой памяти. В остальном они ведут сабя так же, как и обычные. (А кастомный аллокатор к мапе нужен, чтобы не считать память, которую сама эта мапа занимает.)

Answer (score 0):

Крайне признателен @HolyBlackCat за весьма содержательную дискуссию.

Резюмируя вышеизложенное я пришел к выводу что лучше всего хранить сам объект непосредственно в list потому что данный способ не требует никакого дополнительного кода, память под объект выделяется и освобождается в куче а не в стеке.

Просто указатели на объект хранить в list нельзя - память под выделенные объекты освобождаться не будет. Для хранения указателей в list применяйте либо shared_ptr либо метод, предложенный @HolyBlackCat (требуется   свой CustomAllocator + operator delete ) - на мой взгляд весьма большой кусок дополнительного кода.

Comment: Сюда тоже отпишусь. Я не предлагал кастомный аллокатор + `operator new` и `delete` для автоматического освобождения памяти. У меня в примере они использовались только для подсчета занятой памяти.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда я совсем запутался :) - можете убрать map, и все для подсчета памяти - и дать пример - по моему без надстройки память не освободится - я у себя запущу и проверю

Comment: [Клац](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/accb4f4dc4bbec6a).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - но у Вас же в коде указателей нет! Вы сохранили в list struct A и во втором варианте shared_ptr<A> - о чем я и писал :) - что хранить просто указатели на объект в std::list нельзя

Comment: Угу, я действительно не так понял. Мне сначала показалось, что вы говорите, что память утекает если хранить сами объекты, а не shared_ptr.